# Create 2D Grid Based from Width, Height and Total Boxes

Tags: java, math, processing

I'm trying to draw 2048 boxes onto a screen with a width and a height. (I am making this in Java)

I have the following variables:

- **width** = 1024
- **height** = 768
- **population** = 2048

Based on these variables, how can I draw a grid with **x** amount of columns and **y** amount of rows allowing the whole layout to perfectly fit the desired width and height?

**For example:**
I have a width and height of 4 x 4 and a total population of 4, I therefore would have 2 columns and 2 rows.

**Example 2:**
[image: Grid of colored boxes]

I want to reproduce the exact same thing in the screenshot above, but I do not know how many rows and columns I need to loop through as well as the size of each square.

All I know is the total width/height of the window, along with the total number of boxes I want to draw.

Comment: I do not understand, can you give a more complex example with e.g.7x10 dimensions?

Comment: should your box be a square, or rectangle with aspect ratio of window or a rectangle with any aspect ratio?

Comment: Imagine you want to fill your entire computer screen with a random amount of boxes such as 55, and you want them to be in a grid-row layout. My question is, how can I determine how many rows and columns for the grid to be evenly spaced

Comment: @NabinBhandari In my head I was imaging a rectangle would be best, but it doesn't matter too much

Comment: What does the population have to do with the size of the boxes?

Comment: More population, smaller boxes (to fit them all perfectly within the given width/height)

Comment: how would you split up 13 (or any prime for that matter) boxes equally on the screen? You cannot just change the entire basis of your question regarding rectangles. What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: For 2048 cells you'll need 64 columns by 32 rows. Given the height and width each cell should be 1024/64 =16 p wide  768/32 = 24p high.

Comment: If you are asking how to find the divisor of a number (say 2048) see: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111636/141451  . Get all divisors and choose the pair with the difference between them to make it as squarish as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the boxes need to be rectangular, there are multiple possible solutions. eg. for area 12, box can be of 12x1, 1x12, 4x3, 3x4, 6x2, 2x6, etc.. let alone the floating values.

If square boxes are OK:

```
area = available_width * available_height
area_per_box = area / no_of_boxes
length = sqrt(area_per_box)
```

fill grid with this obtained length as width and height of small boxes.

**Another approach would be to fill the grid as you like and scale the grid to your desired dimension.**

Comment: Answer is OK, but only applicable for square boxes though.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to answer questions like this for yourself is to get out a piece of paper and a pencil, and draw out a bunch of examples. Label the width and height of the window, as well as the position and width and height of each individual box. Keep drawing examples until you notice a pattern.

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://HappyCoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time. That being said, I can try to help in a general sense.

First, you need to figure out how many rows and columns your grid should have. There isn't just a single correct way to go from a population to a row and column count. In fact, it might not even be possible- how would you split up a population of 3? There are also multiple solutions: if your population count is 20, then you could have a grid that's 1x20, 2x10, 4x5, 5x4, 10x2, or 20x1. I recommend you **treat this as a separate problem** and post a separate question about that.

But once you have the row and column count, you can use some basic math to figure out the position and size of each box. Again, drawing out some examples would help, but the basics would look like this:

```
  float cellWidth = width/columns;
  float cellHeight = height/rows;

  for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < columns; column++) {

      float cellX = cellWidth*column;
      float cellY = cellHeight*row;

      rect(cellX, cellY, cellWidth, cellHeight);
    }
  }
```

Note that I got this code from [this tutorial](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection), but you'll find examples all over the internet if you do some googling. If you still can't get it working, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly what you tried, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: @Acidic I've edited my answer to include more info about converting a population to a row and column count, but really the primary answer remains the same. You're really asking two separate questions here.